# Why two constructors when using Entity Framework's Code First Reverse Engineer capability?

Tags: constructor, entity-framework-6

I'm learning Entity Framework and have a question.  Why when using EF Code First and Reverse Engineering an existing database do I get two constructors in my context class?  I believe in the example below the first is ensuring my database is not recreated as I am connecting to an existing database, SixteenthSectionLegacy, and the second is identifying the connection string that is used in my app.config file...  Why couldn't/shouldn't both be in the first constructor?

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using EFReverseEngineerTest.Models.Mapping;

namespace EFReverseEngineerTest.Models
{
    public partial class SixteenthSectionLegacyContext : DbContext
    {
        static SixteenthSectionLegacyContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<SixteenthSectionLegacyContext>(null);
        }

        public SixteenthSectionLegacyContext()
            : base("Name=SixteenthSectionLegacyContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<board> boards { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BOARD1> BOARDS1 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Classification> Classifications { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new boardMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BOARD1Map());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClassificationMap());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the question answered?

Answer (score 0):

`: base("Name=SixteenthSectionLegacyContext")` tells EF which connectionstring it sould use by default. You can pass your own connection string name when you create an SixteenthSectionLegacyContext instance in Code.

```
using (var context = new SixteenthSectionLegacyContext("SixteenthSectionLegacyContext_2"))
{
}
```

Add the second connection string name in the `app.config` under  `<connectionStrings> </connectionStrings>`

This is why there are 2 ones, if you don't pass anything the default connection string is used.